# Скрипт SQL для Ora,Postgre и FB

Tags: postgresql, oracle, jdbc, firebird

Скрипт не работает на Oracle и Postgre, но работает на FB

```
select o.ID, ter.ID ter_id
from  ORG o, TERRITORY ter 
join ORGROLES rol on rol.org_id = o.id
```

А так работает везде:

```
select o.ID, ter.ID ter_id
from  TERRITORY ter, ORG o  
join ORGROLES rol on rol.org_id = o.id
```

Вопрос, почему так? Какие ещё есть советы, чтобы избежать непереносимости скриптов на разные СУБД?

Comment: Совет только один: _Никогда_ не смешивайте в одном запросе синтаксис с запятой в from и join. Либо одно, либо другое

Comment: На какой версии FB вы проверяли? Начиная с 2.0 в документации написано, что смешивать явное и неявное соединение недопустимо

Comment: @Герман Борисов  **_2.5.2_**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, есть ли в доке оракла прямое упоминание, но в целом логика примерно следующая: когда вы пишете `from A join B on ...`, после `on` должно идти условие связи таблиц `A` и `B`, а не каких-то других. Вот этот ваш запрос не работает:

```
select o.ID, ter.ID ter_id
from  ORG o, TERRITORY ter 
join ORGROLES rol on rol.org_id = o.id
```

потому что вы пишете `ter join rol`, а в условии связи у вас `rol.org_id = o.id`.
Тут уже был похожий вопрос, там написали, что смешивать разные способы джойнов нельзя. Можно, просто надо делать это правильно.
Почему это работает в FB - без понятия.

> Какие ещё есть советы, чтобы избежать непереносимости скриптов на разные СУБД?

100% переносимость невозможна даже на уровне учебных запросов. В оракле, например, нельзя написать просто `select current_user`, а нужно писать  `select current_user from dual`. Но ни в какой другой СУБД таблицы `dual` нет (я слышал, некоторые даже создают ее в целях обеспечения переносимости). В оракле есть ключевое слово `minus`, хотя по стандарту должно быть `except` (как это есть у всех остальных). И так далее, и тому подобное.